# Не пойму что от меня хочет компилятор

Tags: c++, алгоритм, вектор

Здравствуйте вот есть код, вроде написан правильно, пишу на CodeBlocks:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 template <class elemType>
    elemType& min (const std::vector<elemType> &vec) {
    typename std::vector<elemType>::iterator
    select = vec.begin(), it = next(select), end_it = vec.end();
    for ( ; it != end_it; it++ ) {
        if ( *it < *select ) select = it;
    }
    return *select;
    };

int main()
{
    int massiv[10] = {35, 66, 98, 15, 32, 41, 24, 90, 55, 100};
    std::vector<int> vec_train(massiv,massiv+10);

    min(vec_train);
    return 0;
}
```

Но выдает следующую ошибку:

> error: conversion from 'std::vector::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}' to non-scalar type 'std::vector::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}' requested|

Как такие ошибки вообще расшифровывать самостоятельно, если я только недавно начал учить программирование? Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В функции параметр определен как константная ссылка

```
elemType& min (const std::vector<elemType> &vec) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Поэтому такие функции, как `begin` и `end`  возвращают итератор типа `const_iterator`. Исправьте

```
typename std::vector<elemType>::const_iterator
select = vec.begin(), it = next(select), end_it = vec.end();
```

Также вам следует включить заголовок

```
#include <iterator>
```

так как в программе используется функция `std::next`, объявленная в этом заголовке.

Также имейте в виду, что функция `min` некорректна, так как в общем случае переданный вектор может быть пустым. А это значит, что в функции имеет место обращение к не существующему элементу вектора и, соответственно, разыменование недействительного итератора.

Имеется стандартный алгоритм `std::min_element`, объявленный в заголовке `<algorithm>`, который выполняет поставленную задачу.

Ваша функция может быть определена по аналогии с этим алгоритмом. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class elemType>
auto min( const std::vector<elemType> &vec ) 
{
    auto select = vec.begin();

    if ( select != vec.end() )
    {
        for ( auto it = vec.begin(), end_it = vec.end(); ++it != end_it; ) 
        {
            if ( *it < *select ) select = it;
        }           
    }

    return select;
}

int main() 
{
    int massiv[] = { 35, 66, 98, 15, 32, 41, 24, 90, 55, 100 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( massiv ) / sizeof( *massiv );

    std::vector<int> vec_train( massiv, massiv + N );

    auto it = min( vec_train );

    if ( it != vec_train.end() )
    {
        std::cout << "Minimum is " << *it << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод прогоаммы на консоль

```
Minimum is 15
```

Если ваш компилятор не поддерживает спецификатор типа `auto`, то функцию можно определить как

```
template <class elemType>
typename std::vector<elemType>::const_iterator min( const std::vector<elemType> &vec ) 
{
    typedef typename std::vector<elemType>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    const_iterator select = vec.begin();

    if ( select != vec.end() )
    {
        for ( const_iterator it = vec.begin(), end_it = vec.end(); ++it != end_it; ) 
        {
            if ( *it < *select ) select = it;
        }           
    }

    return select;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за подробное объяснение! =)

Comment: Для пустого вектора UB в коде ТС наступает чуть раньше разыменования - при вызове `next`. Кстати `std::min` для списка инициализации тоже имеет UB при пустой последовательности. Так что это можно вынести в *preconditions*.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> error: conversion from 'std::vector::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}' 
> to non-scalar type 'std::vector::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}' requested
> ```

> Как такие ошибки вообще расшифровывать самостоятельно, если я только недавно начал учить программирование?

Для начала, из текста ошибки надо выкинуть всё лишнее. В данном случае убрать текст в фигурных скобках вместе со скобками. Он ссылается на внутренний для компилятора тип итератора. "aka" означает "also known as", т.е. по сути, синоним, альтернативное имя. Получим:

> ```
> error: conversion from 'std::vector::const_iterator' to non-scalar type
> 'std::vector::iterator' requested
> ```

Здесь уже более чётко видно о чём говорит ошибка:

> ```
> запрошено преобразование из 'std::vector::const_iterator' в нескалярный тип 
> 'std::vector::iterator'
> ```

[Скалярный тип](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#9) это в частности любой арифметический тип, например, `double` или `int`. Между такими типами в c++ предусмотрены неявные преобразования. Т.е. можно написать, скажем:

```
double d = 5.5; 
int i = d;
```

и компилятор не выдаст на это никаких ошибок. В Вашем случае, тип нескалярный, а значит для неявного преобразования из одного типа `T1` в другой `T2` должен быть определён:

- либо конструктор для типа `T2`, принимающий аргумент типа `T1`;
- либо оператор преобразования в типе `Т1` вида `operator T2()`.

Преобразования `std::vector::const_iterator` в `std::vector::iterator` не существует (хотя стоит заметить, что есть обратное преобразование), поэтому компилятор и выдал соответствующую ошибку.

Ну, а про устранение причины ошибки уже подробно расписано в другом ответе, поэтому не вижу смысла повторяться.